# https server hello missing

Tags: centos, nginx, ssl, https

I've setup an `nginx` server, and config it with a https certificate. But I cannot access my server through `https` **occasionally** . In some rare cases, it works well, but **no server hello** in most cases. Using `wireshark`, shows as below

[image: wireshark catptured results]

**EDIT**, below is my `nginx conf`

```
server {
    listen       443 http2 ssl;
    server_name  n1.chengjie.me;
    root        /opt/app/html.n1.chengjie.me;
    index       index.html;
    charset     utf-8;

    access_log  logs/access.n1.chengjie.me.log  main;
    error_log  logs/error.n1.chengjie.me.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/chengjie.me/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/chengjie.me/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/chengjie.me/chain.pem;
    gzip            on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied    expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml application/javascript text/css;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm)$
    {
            expires      7d;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(?:js|css)$
    {
            expires      7d;
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2** Add some test results on my Mac:

`curl -kv "https://n1.chengjie.me/"` result below:

[image: curl error info]

`openssl s_client -connect n1.chengjie.me:443` result below:

[image: openssl-1]

[image: openssl-2]

[image: openssl-3]

**EDIT** Add server tcpdump: `tcpdump -i eth0 '( (tcp) and (dst port ! 22) and (port 443))'`

[image: client wireshark mss values]

[image: server tcpdump mss values]

I see that, `MSS` values changes, client `SYN` with `MSS 1460` but server receives `MSS 1300`, and server `SYN` with `MSS 1460` but client receives `MSS 1300`. And after server receive client's **second** `ACK`, server sends client a `FIN`?? cant't understand why server sends `FIN`.

Comment: Could you also paste logs from `nginx` and configuration file for server?

Comment: @mrc02_kr I can paste config from `nginx`, but since https is not established, there is **no** log from `nginx`

Comment: `nginx` would be responsible for creating the **server hello** response, but the operating system would normally at least acknowledge the TCP packet containing the **client hello** message in a timely manner. You might want to try catching the problem in a server-side traffic dump, and see what is going on there. It might be that something is causing the client hello message to never reach the server, or perhaps the server received it and responded, but the response never reaches your client.

Comment: if you server is accessible from internet, have a check with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ . I have more or less same problem (nginx+let's encrypt). Old device (android < 4.x) would connect, but new won't.

Comment: @telcoM thx, the strange thing is, `https` is OK now and then. I will catch traffic on my server, and see if there is something wrong with it

Comment: @Archemar I've use your link to test my server, and it is OK from the test result. And , I can access my server using my own phone with 4G-network, but still fail when using my Mac with WIFI network

Comment: @Archemar this is my test result [https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=n1.chengjie.me](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=n1.chengjie.me)